# How to achieve keyboard accessibility in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, accessibility

```
class _IrisTapState extends State<IrisTap> {
  bool _disabled = false;
  final FocusNode _gestureDetectorFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _gestureDetectorFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setAttribute({
    required String attribute,
    required String value,
  }) {
    if (document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane') != null) {
      final shadowRoot = document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane')?.shadowRoot;
      document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane')?.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');

      if (shadowRoot != null) {
        final canvas = shadowRoot
            .querySelector('flt-scene-host')
            ?.querySelector('flt-scene')
            ?.querySelector('flt-canvas-container')
            ?.querySelector('canvas');

        if (canvas != null) {
          canvas.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
          canvas.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
          canvas.setAttribute(attribute, value);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < shadowRoot.childNodes.length; i++) {
          if (shadowRoot.childNodes[i] is FormElement) {
            final fe = shadowRoot.childNodes[i] as FormElement;

            if (shadowRoot.childNodes[i] is ButtonElement ||
                shadowRoot.childNodes[i] is AnchorElement ||
                document.querySelectorAll('[onclick]').isNotEmpty) {
              final ie = shadowRoot.childNodes[i] as TextAreaElement;
              ie.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
            }
            if (fe.querySelector('input[autocomplete="on"]') != null) {
              final ie =
                  fe.querySelector('input[autocomplete="on"]') as InputElement;

              if (ie.getAttribute(attribute) == null) {
                ie.setAttribute(attribute, value);
              }
            }
            if (fe.querySelector('input[autocomplete="off"]') != null) {
              final ie =
                  fe.querySelector('input[autocomplete="off"]') as InputElement;

              if (ie.getAttribute(attribute) == null) {
                ie.setAttribute(attribute, value);
              }
            }
            if (fe.querySelector('textarea') != null) {
              final ie = fe.querySelector('textarea') as TextAreaElement;

              if (ie.getAttribute(attribute) == null) {
                ie.setAttribute(attribute, value);
              }
            }
          }
          if (shadowRoot.childNodes[i] is InputElement) {
            final ie = shadowRoot.childNodes[i] as InputElement;
            ie.setAttribute(attribute, value);
          }

          if (shadowRoot.childNodes[i] is TextAreaElement) {
            final ie = shadowRoot.childNodes[i] as TextAreaElement;
            ie.setAttribute(attribute, value);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TapDebouncer(
      cooldown: IrisTap.coolDown,

      // your tap handler moved here
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        TapDebouncerFunc? onTapHandler,
      ) {
        return IrisAccessibility(
          label: widget.semanticLabel ?? '',
          isButton: true,
          excludeChildSemantics: widget.semanticLabel != null,
          child: MouseRegion(
            cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
            child: Focus(
              focusNode: _gestureDetectorFocusNode,
              autofocus: true,
              child: RawKeyboardListener(
                focusNode: FocusNode(),
                onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
                  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                    _gestureDetectorFocusNode.requestFocus();
                    setAttribute(attribute: 'aria-label', value: 'sometext');
                  }
                },
                child: GestureDetector(
                  behavior: widget.behavior,

                  /// Using onTapUp to avoid multiple taps being registered for long
                  /// presses (user holds button fo > 2-3 seconds)
                  onTapUp: (details) async {
                    _gestureDetectorFocusNode.requestFocus();
                    setAttribute(attribute: 'aria-label', value: 'sometext');
                    await _onTap(details);
                  },
                  onTapDown: widget.onTapDown,
                  onTapCancel: widget.onTapCancel,
                  child: Semantics(
                    enabled: true,
                    explicitChildNodes: true,
                    label: 'welcomescreenbutton',
                    child: widget.child,
                    button: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I have used Semantics, RawKeyboardListener, Focus widgets but nothing is working.
I'm testing using Evinced tool for accessibility. But it is giving keyboard accessibility issue. How to achieve it?

Keyboard Accessible
Keyboard-only users do not interpret the element as interactable.
URL:
http://localhost:53303/
Component:
fd346586
Selector:
flt-glass-pane

Severity:
Critical
Cause:
Missing or incorrect semantics prevent the keyboard User-Agent from interpreting an element as interactable.

Effect:
Interface interaction is limited for keyboard-only users.

Read more in Evinced Knowledge Base
How To Fix:
(Recommended) Add an element that better reflects the element's purpose. Interactive elements do not need any additions because they are focusable by nature.
Add a tabindex attribute with the value of “0” to the element.